# Cannot Resolve setSelectedNavigationItem(),addTab,newTab() method

Tags: android, android-studio, tabs, android-actionbar

I'm new to android and I'm making a sliding tab layout project. Though I'm facing a slight problem in my project. In my class which extends `AppCompatActivity` there is an error saying

> cannot resolve setSelectedNavigationItem() method.

Its also showing the same problem with the `addTab()` and `newTab()` method. I know something is been missing out but I'm not been able to find that. Please help me my code goes like this :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
        android:id="@+id/materialTabHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity ="fill"
        app:primaryColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:accentColor="@color/colorWhite" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

and the java class goes like this :

```
public class ComparingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  MaterialTabListener{

private Toolbar toolbar;
private MaterialTabListener tabHost;
private ViewPager viewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comparing);
    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    tabHost = (MaterialTabListener)this.findViewById(R.id.materialTabHost);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)this.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTab()
                        .setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}
```

everything is working fine but these three problem are needed to be sorted out for my project to run. 
The logcat snap is like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr3qX.jpg)

Comment: Can you post your logcat too.

Comment: is `setSelectedNavigationItem` of  `MaterialTabListener` ?

Comment: not its for the the tabhost to change the page when selected.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `dependency` to your `gradle` file,

```
dependencies {
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
}
```

Comment: already added sir. It's just giving me the error with that and because of that I'm confused how to check for the problem.

Comment: Post your logcat. You don't have to call me sir dude.

Comment: thanks for that I've added the logcat's snap in  my post. You can have a look over that

Comment: Did you `sync` your project after adding the dependency?

Comment: Yes, and i did it again after your call too. But the problem still remains there.

Comment: one more thing I'd like to add here is that my setOnPageChangeListener is deprecated. So is it because of that or something else?

Comment: I find out the error as it was in the defintion of the variable tabHost. I need to specify tabHost under the MaterialTabHost and what I was doing was private MaterialTabListener tabHost; which was dynamically hampering it to be diffined under the setSelectedNavigationItem. Btw Thank you for the consideration